# Fourier analysis of Krylov subspace method

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

I am looking up on internet to find a resource in which Fourier analysis of Krylov subspce method (CG, GMRES method) were studied. Can anyone introduce a reference in which the topic was explained.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are looking for. Do you wish to analyze the behavior of CG, etc. when these methods are applied to linear systems obtained by discretizing smooth operators and exploit this connection? If yes, then this is an interesting question. If no, then you should edit your question to include more details.

Comment: In particular, I need a reference to analysis convergence behavior of Krylov subspace method, like CG or GMRES. I think what you mention is almost what I want. Seems this paper [http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~liesen/Publicat/LiTiGAMM.pdf] investigates convergence analysis of GMRES. I only read its abstract.